# Django Import variable from urls into views

Tags: python, django, import

These are both inside the same `app`

#### urls.py

```
from billing import get_integration

stripe_obj = get_integration("stripe_example")
```

#### view.py

```
from app.urls import stripe_obj
```

Currently this returns `cannot import name stripe_obj`. What am I missing?

Comment: You could potentially be running into circular import issue. Can you revisit your implementation? May be put the integration logic in the views rather than the urls ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten to define your settings for stripe_obj?

Check out what tuxcanfly has done [here](https://github.com/agiliq/merchant/blob/master/docs/offsite/paypal.rst).

You must first define the config/settings for the object. In your case, replace pay_pal with stripe_obj.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...,
'paypal.standard.pdt',
...)

 MERCHANT_SETTINGS = {
 ...,
 'pay_pal': {
     "WPP_USER" : '...',
     "WPP_PASSWORD" : '...',
     "WPP_SIGNATURE" : '...',
     "RECEIVER_EMAIL" : '...',
     # Below attribute is optional
     "ENCRYPTED": True
 }
 ...}

 PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = MERCHANT_SETTINGS['pay_pal']['RECEIVER_EMAIL']
```

Comment: Justin, this is incorrect. your merchant settings should be `stripe` while I am looking to import a variable created in `urls.py` into `view.py`.